# Creating composite key for JPA/Hibernate vs artificial Long id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What would be the better way to map an entity in jpa that only has 2 columns, which are both a part of primary key?

1. Self reference entity Java class as primary key
2. Create POJO for primary key
3. Introduce "Long id" as an artificial id to avoid mapping composite key

Comment: If option 2 implies creating an Embeddable and using that as an EmbeddedId, then I think that is the only option that actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for sounds like a many-to-many relationship. If there is no other choice, other than to create an entity for that, this is how you do it.

> **First**, create your embeddable composite key

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BaseKey {
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

> **Second**, create your entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnyEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BaseKey key;

}
```

Comment: For now, i have made an entity class (UserRoles) serializable, marked itself with @IdClass(UserRoles.class). It is both an entity and an id class at the same time

Comment: `@IdClass` annotation is less verbose but has its own drawbacks. I recommend using `@EmbeddedId` especially if you have FK  in your key and/or going to use values of your key.

Answer (score -1):

I will choose option 3 is to have a `surrogate key` as Long Id. Cause you would want to avoid updating multiple rows in case a part of your composite key changes. also note that even the index references have to be updated.

for example - In below case lets say Company ID/Employee no changes then you would have update multiple rows in case Employee and then Phone table as well.

```
Employee                    Phone   
---------                   --------
Company ID (PK)             Phone no
Employee No (PK)            Company ID (FK)
Name                        Employee No (FK)
```

Rather if you add surrogate key in Employee then only single update in Employee table.

```
Employee                    Phone   
---------                   --------
ID (PK)                     Phone no
Company ID (UK)             Employee ID (FK)
Employee No (UK)            
Name
```